# Who should pay for accidental damage if company didn't apply for insurance?

Tags: ethics, india, employer

I've a company issued macbook pro laptop and recently I damaged the screen by accident, after that I have found out that my company never had an insurance against that laptop. Although apple care is very costly, getting a standard insurance is quite cheap i.e 2000 INR per year, only issue is longer claim process.

If it had been a personal laptop I would have ensured to have an insurance given the price of that laptop is quite high.

In this case who should bear the cost of damage? Is it right for the company to give any kind of asset to us and force to bear the cost of damage without having an insurance in place?

Comment: check your company policy handbook.

Comment: Is someone actually trying to make you pay for it, or is it some theoretical question bout the law around it?

Comment: policy handbook says me and company has to bear the cost of damage at 80%:20% share respectively. although I'm up for paying, want to understand whether it is ethical for an employer to ask me to pay the cost while they didn't apply for insurance

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm an employee, not a contractor, and the company I work for is India based

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be allowed in India. This is crazy! "Deductions are permitted from an employee’s wages, but only for specified reasons (eg, on account of fines, deductions for damage to or loss of goods expressly entrusted to the employee and recovery of loans or advances). Deductions are generally permitted only up to 50% of the employee’s wages." Source: https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=fa2fb547-5828-419a-bd3b-4ef01b612643

Answer (score 9):

> In this case who should bear the cost of damage?

When company property is accidentally damaged, the company *should* bear the cost of that damage, in my opinion. It's up to them to decide to carry insurance or not. (Of course, there's often a difference between *should* and *legally required to do so.*)

> Is it right for the company to give any kind of asset to us and force
> to bear the cost of damage without having an insurance in place?

It depends what you mean by "give".

If the asset was a gift, then you can choose to repair it or not, because you own it.

If the asset was lent to you to use in a work capacity, then it remains company property and (unless local laws and contracts dictate otherwise) the company must provide a replacement for you to use. Check your contract and the company handbook. Also check local laws.

> policy handbook says me and company bears the cost of damage at
> 80%:20% share respectively. although I'm up for paying, want to
> understand whether it is ethical for an employer to ask me to pay the
> cost while they didn't apply for insurance

If that's what you agreed to when you were hired, then you can either pay for your part of the repairs or talk with your attorney.

It's not something I would have agreed to. For me, that would have been a show-stopper when deciding to accept a job offer. But it's also not common in my part of the world.

Comment: Basically. If he's in country B and the company is in country A, the norms of country B should apply. Unless he signed a contract specific to contractors that says otherwise or the employee handbook explicitly mentions country A. If I did agree to pay 80% I would also refuse to use their equipment and just use my own tho.

Comment: Fair enough. For some reason I thought he said he was a contractor. I see now he's an employee too.

Answer (score 3):

In my job, I have the duty to lock my computer and some other things up when they are not used. That's something a company can reasonably ask you to do. What if my laptop falls off the desk if I don't watch out? That's an accident. My company cannot reasonably ask me to have no accidents. Because it's in the nature of an accident that it just happens, even if you take reasonable care. So the *normal* thing to happen is that you report any damage to the company's computer to the company, and they are responsible for the damage.

There is no requirement for the company to have any insurance; if they decide that it is on average cheaper to pay for damages out of their own pocket than paying premiums to an insurance company, that is entirely up to them and may be actually a good decision. Still it means that *you* shouldn't have to pay.

But that is all from the perspective of a western country. Where I live, I'm only responsible if I deliberately destroy company property, or in cases of gross negligence (and gross negligence would require extraordinary stupidity on your part). In India, things may be different. If they ask you to pay, the best would be to take your contract to an employment lawyer and ask for independent advice. In any case, there is no reason why you would pay for a new computer. My computer isn't worth anything near what a new replacement would cost, so the damage would not be anything near what a new replacement would cost either.